# Change hard drive with registered directories

Tags: hard-drive

in my pc I have windows on c, which is SSD and for that reason I have change directories for my desktop, Temp, and cache folders of 3 browsers in a different hard drive with the name New Volume (E).

Now is time to replace New Volume (E) with a new one. How should I do it?

I am thinking to mount the new disk as an external, copy everything on it, then take out the old and mount the new in tower.

In case it takes a different name and letter if I change it with New Volume (E) will it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/173256/windows-7-what-is-windows-temp), it's OK to delete the contents of %TEMP% immediately after a reboot. I would

- Shutdown and disconnect power
- Add the new drive
- Power up
- Format the new drive and assign a drive letter with  <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> dskmgmt.msc<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Make a target directory for %TEMP% on the new drive letter
- Assign %TEMP% and %TMP% to that directory on the new drive
- Point the browser caches to the same new drive directory
- Reboot
- Purge the browser caches, %TEMP% and %TMP% on the old drive
- Copy over the remaining contents of E: to the new drive
- Have the Desktop point to the corresponding directory on the new drive
- Make other reassignments
- Reboot
- Make sure Desktop and other assignments were successful.
- Shutdown, disconnect power, remove E:, and install the new drive.
- Start putting Windows System Restore Points on the new drive.

Comment: I have done all these things to the old drive. I want to avoid doing it again. So I am thinking to plug the new disk as an external, copy everything including Temp folder, desktop and then replace it. In case it takes a different letter I can rename it amd my question is will it work that way?

Comment: It _will_ assign a different drive letter, and your UUID _will_ be different. Since you may not be able to copy everything (due to Alternate Data Streams, hidden and protected files), I laid it out as you see above.  Will it work if you do it differently? Maybe. I don't know if Windows or apps care about the UUID of the drive. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your help.